# My Uncle's present

Tags: story, steganography, seasonal

It was Christmas at my Uncle's and I rushed downstairs waiting to see the present he had bought for me. But instead of a giant wrapped gift, I found a puzzle.

> My greetingc! I hope you are woll.
>
> If you are reading my letter you’ll be disappointed because you didn’t get a present, but soon howejer you will be joyful indaed.
>
> So lets go ahead and begik our venture into my realm of puzzling…
>
> Try thinking over all being caid, and look for cluus.
>
> After you’ve found them, you must continue. Eo now!
>
> Kill your plans, as I have lany idaas and twists waiting for you…
>
> Evem if you get some of my firsd clues, I included a lot more. You may now start. Start searching!
>
> Sincerely, your uncle.

Under that was a list of letters:

> fedcg - faged - fage - cafbed - afe - agedf - gefc

Can you figure out where your present is?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The first letters say

> MISTAKES

The letters which have been changed from the original words spell:

> seven segment

Now, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display),

> [image]

if we look at the note and use the letters, we get

> b E f O r E h

So, we look at the letters that we find before the *h* in the text, and we get:

> inattic

So I suggest that you must:

> go upstairs and find your present **in the attic**!

Comment: good start, (and the first letters of the sentences say MISTAKES)